# Multiple Ruby on Rails Model Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database

I am trying to access location details thru a shipment model that has an origin and a destination.

I would like to access the location information thru a call like this:

```
Shipment.find(###).origin ->
   :id => "###", :cs => "Springfield, Mo", :latitude => "#####", :longitude => "####"

Shipment.find(###).dest ->
   :id => "###", :cs => "Springfield, Mo", :latitude => "#####", :longitude => "####"
```

I have the following setup

shipment.rb:

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :vehicles, dependent: :destroy

  validates :origin_id, :dest_id, :presence => true

  attr_accessible :origin_id, :dest_id, (more attributes...)
end
```

location.rb

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cs, :latitude, :longitude
  geocoded_by :cs
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :cs_changed?
  has_many :shipments, :foreign_key => :origin_id
  has_many :shipments, :foreign_key => :dest_id
end
```

---

I think it is something like this:

```
has_one :origin, :class => "Location", :origin_id
```

or

```
scope :origin, -> (:origin_id) { Location.find(:origin_id)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
...

  belongs_to :origin, class: 'Location', foreign_key: 'origin_id'
  belongs_to :dest, class: 'Location', foreign_key: 'dest_id'

end
```

For older rails

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...

      belongs_to :origin, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'origin_id'
      belongs_to :dest, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'dest_id'

 end
```

Then for origin location

```
Shipment.find(###).origin
```

Then for destination location

```
Shipment.find(###).dest
```

Answer (score 2):

shipment.rb

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :vehicles, dependent: :destroy

  validates :origin_id, :dest_id, :presence => true

  attr_accessible :origin_id, :dest_id
  belongs_to :origin, :class_name => 'Location', :foreign_key => 'origin_id'
  belongs_to :destination, :class_name =>'Location', :foreign_key => 'dest_id'
end
```

Comment: `Shipment.last.origin
  ArgumentError: Unknown key: class`

Comment: you are using rails 3 or 4?

Comment: It should be `class_name` instead of `class` for rails 3 please check my post

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Shipment` model actually holds the foreign key, it's a `belongs_to :origin` situation, I believe. Look into the [RoR guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more info.

Comment: but it would be `belongs_to :location` because origin is not a model

Comment: @BigAlRubyNewbie The `belongs_to` method specifies the name of the relationship. You can specify the class name (`Location`) using the `class_name` option.